# Mention Role with Hikari and Lighbulb

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots, hikaricp

I want to mention specific role when I use / with hikari
my code:

```
@plugin.command
@lightbulb.command('tag', 'test tag!')
@lightbulb.implements(lightbulb.SlashCommand)
async def tag(ctx):
    await ctx.respond("<@&1067308654342197269>")
```

Command work, but I don't get any mention from my bot
[bot run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1puv.png)

I want to get mention like this
[tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCu6t.png)

What should I do with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved lol,
by using

> role_mentions=True

```
@plugin.command
@lightbulb.command('tag', 'test tag!')
@lightbulb.implements(lightbulb.SlashCommand)
async def tag(ctx: lightbulb.Context) -> None:
    await ctx.respond(f"<@&1067308654342197269>", role_mentions=True)
```